# Can't get number based javascript regex pattern to work

Tags: javascript, regex

I know it should be simple, and yes i've tested on online regex sites, but i just can't get this to work.

> Input string: "w_(number from 1-99),h_(number from 1-99)", e.g: **"w_34,h_34"**
>
> Expected Output: number replaced, e.g **"w_50,h_50"**

Test:

```
'w_34,h_34'.replace('w_[1-9][0-9],h_[1-9][0-9]', 'w_50,h_50')
```

But it just returns the original string. (w_34,h_34)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression to take advantage of the regexp syntax

```
'w_34,h_34'.replace(/w_[1-9][0-9]?,h_[1-9][0-9]?/, 'w_50,h_50')
```

This will solve to only 2 digits of numbers. An alternative would be to use the `*` operator.

```
'w_34,h_34'.replace(/w_[1-9][0-9]*,h_[1-9][0-9]*/, 'w_50,h_50')
```

Which would allow n-length numbers to match.

Comment: A more flexible number match would be `[1-9][0-9]*`. Handles anything from 1 onwards

Comment: @Phil I opted to use the ? optional operator instead of the * 0 or more.

Comment: @Gabriel But that limits you to numbers between 1 and 99

Comment: @Phil yeah I know. It seemed in line with the OP's intentions, though there is technically very little difference in performance. I will add the other alternative and explain the diff in the answer.